# SwiftUI UIViewControllerRepresentable, what does Coordinator(self) mean?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

What does Coordinator(self) mean when making a UIViewControllerRepresentable (to use a UIKit component in SwiftUI)?  I am a little confused on what the “self” represents.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
            }
            
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not show pictures of code. And _really_ do not show _tiny useless_ pictures of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` always means "the current instance". So when you write...

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

... `self` means "this ImagePicker instance".

You are saying this because of the way the initializer for Coordinator is declared:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var parent: ImagePicker
    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```

Coordinator needs a `parent` in order to be initialized; you *are* initializing a Coordinator and you are *telling* it who the `parent` should be, namely *you* (i.e. `self`, this ImagePicker).

If these concepts give you trouble, you might need to study up on what types and instances are (object-oriented programming) and/or how Swift initializers and initialization are expressed.

Comment: ImagePicker is a value not an instance. If ImagePicker is init again then Coordinator won't have the correct value so I think Coordinator(self) is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`Coordinator(self)` is a mistake that is in unfortunately is in many examples. `self` represents the struct which is immediately discarded after SwiftUI update so it makes no sense of the coordinator object to hang on to it. Any function calls on self won't do anything. The proper way to use a `Coordinator` is shown in Apple's [Fruta sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui), PaymentButton.swift and in your code would look something like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode


    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        context.coordinator.imagePicker       
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.didPickImage = { image in
            self.image = image
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        lazy var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController =  {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            return picker
        }()
        
        var didPickImage: ((Void) -> UIImage)?

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                didPickImage?(uiImage)
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```