# @Observation: Generic binding in SwiftUI crossing UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
protocol ItemViewable {
    var name:String { get set }
}

@Observable class Car:ItemViewable, Hashable, Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs:Car, rhs:Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String = "My Car"
}



@Observable final class TopViewModel {
    var cars = [Car(), Car(), Car(), Car()]
    @ObservationIgnored var ds:UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int,Car>?
    func computeSnapshot() {
        var newSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Car>()
        newSnapshot.appendSections([0])
        newSnapshot.appendItems(cars, toSection: 0)
        ds?.apply(newSnapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}


struct TopView: View {
    @State var model = TopViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        
        TestCollectionView()
            .environment(model)
            .onAppear {
                model.computeSnapshot()
            }
    }
}




@MainActor struct TestCollectionView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Environment(TopViewModel.self) var model:TopViewModel
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UICollectionView {
        context.coordinator.collectionView.register(TestCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TestCell")
        context.coordinator.setupDatasource()
        return context.coordinator.collectionView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) { }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        
        var collectionView:UICollectionView
        private var parent: TestCollectionView
     
        init(_ cv: TestCollectionView) {
            parent = cv
            collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: Coordinator.createLayout())
            super.init()
            collectionView.backgroundColor = .orange
            collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
            collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
            collectionView.delegate = self
        }
        
        static func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
            return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
                let inset: CGFloat = 8
                let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/CGFloat(3)), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
                let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
                item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: inset, leading: inset, bottom: inset, trailing: inset)
                let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/CGFloat(3)))
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
                return section
            }
        }
        
        func setupDatasource() {
            updateLayout()
            let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TestCell, Car> { cell, indexPath, car in
                cell.setupFor(car: car)
            }
            parent.model.ds = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Car>(collectionView: collectionView) { (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, car: Car) -> TestCell? in
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: car)
                cell.setupFor(car: car)
                return cell
            }
        }
        
        func updateLayout() {
            collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(Coordinator.createLayout(), animated: true)
        }
        
    }
    
}



class TestCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var car:Car?
    let container = ItemViewContainer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        addSubview(container)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if container.frame != bounds {
            container.frame = bounds
        }
    }
    
    func setupFor(car:Car) {
        self.car = car
        guard let car = self.car else { return }
        container.setupItem(item: car)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    
}


class ItemViewContainer: UIView {
    
    var info:UIViewController?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .brown
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if info?.view.frame != bounds {
            info?.view.frame = bounds
        }
    }
    
    func setupItem<T:ItemViewable>(item:T) {
        info?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        info = UIHostingController(rootView: ItemInfo<Car>(item: $item)) // <-- ERROR: Cannot find '$item' in scope
        addSubview(info!.view)
    }
    
}

struct ItemInfo<T:ItemViewable>: View {
    @Binding var item:T
    var body: some View {
        Text("TEST")
    }
}
```

I am getting an error, `Cannot find '$item' in scope` (line 171).

This is a simplified version of actual code I have to work with where a collection view is used inside SwiftUI. Model is passed around and would like to know how to drive a SwiftUI with a model that adopts the `ItemViewable` protocol on top.

How can I use the `car` model inside the `ItemInfo` as a generic. I am basically trying to replicate what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77433335/swiftui-pass-binding-as-generic?noredirect=1#comment136512029_77433335) but in a setting where I am forced to have UIKit views in between one of them is a UICollectionView via `UIViewRepresentable`.

I think I need to use `@Bindable` since I am using `@Observation` now as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) but not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You should probably stick with ObservableObjects. You won’t be able to get a Binding in a class but you can use Combine with UIKit,  you should be using Bindable anyway if you stay with this setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `ItemViewable` class-bound and `Observable`:

```
protocol ItemViewable: AnyObject, Observable
```

If some of the `ItemViewable` implementations are structs/not `Observable`, you cannot do this generically.

Then you can use `@Bindable`:

```
@Bindable var item: T

var body: some View {
    // now ItemInfo can get a Binding from item
    TextField("", text: $item.name)
}
```

Note that if you don't need a `Binding` in `ItemInfo`, you don't need `@Bindable` at all. Just simply declare `var item: T`.

When you pass the item in `setupItem`, you don't need the `$`, since `item` is not a property wrapper.

```
info = UIHostingController(rootView: ItemInfo(item: item))
```

I'll add some views to `TopView`:

```
VStack {
    TestCollectionView()
        .environment(model)
        .onAppear {
            model.computeSnapshot()
        }
        Text(model.cars[0].name)
        Button("Change") {
            model.cars[0].name = "Foo"
            model.cars.append(Car())
            model.computeSnapshot()
        }
}
```

You can now type in the text field, and see the `Text(model.cars[0].name)` change. Tapping the button also updates everything correctly.

Side note: [`Coordinator(self)` is an anti-pattern,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74525403/5133585) you should pass `TopViewModel` to the coordinator directly, if that's all you need from `parent`.

Comment: I think I adopted the changes you suggest but I still get the error. Probably I am not following exactly what you outlined? Change https://gist.github.com/zumacc/52e4f2825136d11167cc903dfebaeb0b

Comment: I'll check the Coordinator(self) anti pattern out. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @zumzum Oops, I forgot to mention that you don't need `$`. Just pass `item`.

Comment: Error: `Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected argument type 'Car'`

Comment: @zumzum Have you kept the `<Car>` type argument? You shouldn't use `<Car>`. You are doing this generically, right? I added my code as a comment to the gist. Please take a look.

Comment: It now works. This is great. Thanks you! https://gist.github.com/zumacc/52e4f2825136d11167cc903dfebaeb0b